# Progressing from learning by writing things down and reviewing to just doing

Tags: parents, adult-child, learning, working-parents, elearning

1. A child, in school, remembers things by writing them down and going over them.
2. An adult, just remembers things (even, ad they are said to them, in conversation).

So, my question is, (as, adults, are still our children, and we must take care of them as parents), how does a person progress, or manage to progress, from stage one, above, to stage two, above?

How do they do it?

Thanks

Comment: You may want to rethink the premise of your question: children learn to read and write in a useful way (e.g. fast enough in writing and reading) only after a certain age, but learn e.g. songs a lot sooner. I don’t think that written information is the key element in learning. And there are cultures that don’t have any form of written information and still function just fine, for all ages.

Comment: "A child, in school, remembers things by writing them down and going over them. An adult, just remembers things (even, ad they are said to them, in conversation)." This is ridiculously generalizing. Many people learn different ways, and no-one learns the exact same way you learned/learn. Maybe you can change your question to be less assuming? This is currently saying you think that there are only "two steps" in learning for everyone.

Comment: Well, I'm not aware of how others might learn, perhaps, even, in a different way.

Comment: Could you please outline some possibilities? I am extremely interested. It would be very constructive and useful. Thank you.

Comment: I, as a child, did not learn by writing things down. I rarely took notes in school, and I reviewed someone else's notes/the textbook before an exam. As an adult, I learn more or less the same way: I read/listen to something, and re-read/re-listen to review. Many adults still find writing things down helpful to learning; there is nothing wrong with this.

Answer (score 1):

I still only retain by writing things down, and specifically hearing them as well. Before I was able to use a Text-to-Speech. Plugin or adaption for my computer, I didn't retain anything without reading and writing it down almost word for word, multiple times.

Take them to get assessed for a learning disability.

Comment: What in the question leads you to suggest assessment for learning disability? I read the question as general interest and don't find a specific problem in there.

Comment: Because it sounds like a concern with working memory and executive functioning skills. Many types of learning disabilities have these issues present and they persist into adulthood because they are engrained in the very nature of someone's learning needs. If it is at a degree that a parent would still notice and have concern over then it may be an underlying sign that something needs to be assessed. Trauma can cause cognitive issues as well as many other things. An assessment can recommend assistive tech, simple modifications to processes, or a specific therapy may greatly assist if diagnosed.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone has their own preferences in how they learn. The preferences can change over time, but the pattern you described is not something that occurs for everyone or even marks adulthood.

> Although many of us remain fairly constant in our learning preference
> throughout time, styles can and do change with some regularity—this
> can be influenced by your learningstyles can and do change with some
> regularity—this can be influenced by your learning environment—perhaps
> after several years at university you’ll discover that you have become
> more of a read/write learner than you were in high school. [[Learning Styles](https://web.wlu.ca/learning_resources/pdfs/Learning_Styles.pdf)]

If you want to change your learning style, practice might help but in the end every brain has their favourite way to percieve data.